# MYSQL WHERE id = 0 it should show total result

Tags: mysql

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e30f0d/15)

In this fiddle example i m trying to use WHERE o.d_id = 1 or 2,3,4 etc but if i use d_id= 0 it should show the total result or we can say the where clause should not work if d_id = 0.

Comment: No.  This is not a complete question, and we should not have to grope through your Fiddle to figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Great fiddle - what do you need to do?

Comment: i m asking simple question. d_id = 1 shows filters the result and shows who has this id and similarly if i use d_id = 0 the complete WHERE clause should not work it should show the result like it is showing now.

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please understand that we're all volunteers here. Your question will get more attention if it's clearly stated. Plus, the effort required to state a question clearly will often lead you to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a conditional style WHERE clause like this....

```
 WHERE (?inputvalue = 0 OR ?inputvalue = d_id)
```

In this case the ?inputvalue is whatever search term you want. You'll provide it from your programming language.

**edit** Notice that in many queries you can specify an input value just once. For example, if all you want is  `WHERE d_id = 17` that's easy to specify. You just put the 17 in and you're done.

But, if you follow my suggestion you need to repeat the input value.  You need  `WHERE (0 = 17 OR d_id = 17)`. That will, when you give it 17, filter your result set to find the seventeens.

And, if you give it 0, like this `WHERE ( 0 = 0 OR d_id = 0 )` it will find all results, not filtering on just the zeroes. That's good because there aren't any zeros.

Comment: actually d_id is a distributor id so i want to filter result for specific distributor. But i m confuse there are two "?inputvalue" in your answer how should i use?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, that's not how `WHERE` works. If you write a statement like `WHERE id = 0`, you ask your database to return just the rows where the `id` column is set to `0`. If you want your database to return all values, you have to skip this condition completly

Comment: Yes i know i inserted few dates dummy data. but i have a huge data. if it returns null it should show 0

Comment: `Null` and `0` are not the same

Comment: yes, null remain null but atleast show result as null.